# Dealing with thousands of similar errors

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, compiler-errors, logfiles

In my project the definitions.h file with some definitions has been changed.
As a result a thousands of compiler erros appeared.
The definitions.h contains the definitions of thousands structs and types, but only a small part of them is relevant to my code.
I want to systemize the errors log file and find which structures are relevant.
For example structure a.b.c has been changed to d.f.g.
I want some tool or script to find all place it causes an error.

To be clear, i want from the list of thousand compiler erros obtain a small (50-100) list of similar errors.

Thanks, Mark

Comment: You already have such a tool, it's the actual compiler. It will list all errors in a nice formatted way, with file-names and line-numbers, and maybe even function names. You can use that list to filter out the errors you are interested in, but it won't do much help just fixing those as you still need to get all other errors fixed as well to be able to build.

Comment: ' As a result a thousands of compiler erros appeared' - lol, as if this is unusual behaviour.  Just wait until you try to link it:)

Answer (score 0):

you cannot argue with compilers. If it says there are thousands of errors you have to resolve them (if you don't want to change compilation flags). You can print the output to a file and go through them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible in general. Think about it logically: if it were feasible for a tool to "collapse" many errors into a single error where they all share the same root cause, then your compiler would already be doing it for you.